# Simplifying an Expression Involving a Summation

Tags: summation

Can anyone think of a way to simplify

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{k - 1} \right]
$$

to a more elegant expression? I've been trying to tweak it using the binomial theorem after expanding it but it's just looking uglier and uglier.

Edit:

---

So far I've been able to rewrite it as

$$
n - \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} {k - 1 \choose j}\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)^j
$$

by expanding the summation and making use of the binomial theorem.

Comment: The sum of 1 is easy, and the rest is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

With the abbreviation $q=\frac{n-1}{n}$ your sum can be written as 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 - \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{k - 1} \right)
=\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 - q^{k - 1} \right)
=\sum_{k = 1}^n 1 - \sum_{k = 1}^n q^{k - 1} 
= n - \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
$$
The last term is the well-known geometric sum. Now using
$$q-1=\frac{n-1}{n}-1= \frac{n-1-n}{n} = -\frac{1}{n}$$ 
the last expressioncan be simplified as
$$ n - \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
= n + n(q^n-1)= nq^n = n \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^n,
$$
and therefore  the final result is 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 - \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{k - 1} \right)
= n \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^n
$$